# How do I make a Button in the titlebar clickable?

Tags: winui-3

I'm trying to follow the [style guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/titlebar-design#people) to add a person button to the titlebar but I am unable to make it clickable. (I can tab to it an trigger it via spacebar, but the title bar prevents all interaction)

I followed the recommendations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk#interactive-content) but none of them work.

The WinAppSdk solution leaves me with the system titlebar overlapping the custom titlebar, and when I click the portion that is showing on the custom titlebar the click does not register.

The UWP solution (Z-Index) does not work either.

ChatGPT says I should implement my own custom drag solution and forget the TitleBar completely. (with a bunch of non-functional code)

Is there a way to make an interactive titlebar in WinUI3? Is there a Git of a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sample app based on the link you provided, and it works.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="TitleBarExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TitleBarExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <Grid
            x:Name="AppTitleBar"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Height="48">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    x:Name="LeftPaddingColumn"
                    Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    x:Name="IconColumn"
                    Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    x:Name="TitleColumn"
                    Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    x:Name="LeftDragColumn"
                    Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    x:Name="PersonButtonColumn"
                    Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    x:Name="RightDragColumn"
                    Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    x:Name="RightPaddingColumn"
                    Width="0" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image
                x:Name="TitleBarIcon"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="16"
                Height="16"
                Margin="8,0,0,0"
                Source="/Images/WindowIcon.png" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Margin="4,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                Text="App title" />
            <Button
                x:Name="PersonButton"
                Grid.Column="4"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Content="Person" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="WindowContent">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WinRT.Interop;

namespace TitleBarExample;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly AppWindow _appWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _appWindow = GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow();

        // Check to see if customization is supported.
        // The method returns true on Windows 10 since Windows App SDK 1.2, and on all versions of
        // Windows App SDK on Windows 11.
        if (AppWindowTitleBar.IsCustomizationSupported() is true)
        {
            AppWindowTitleBar titleBar = _appWindow.TitleBar;
            titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
            titleBar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
            AppTitleBar.Loaded += AppTitleBar_Loaded;
            AppTitleBar.SizeChanged += AppTitleBar_SizeChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            // In the case that title bar customization is not supported, hide the custom title bar
            // element.
            AppTitleBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            // Show alternative UI for any functionality in
            // the title bar, such as search.
        }
    }

    internal enum Monitor_DPI_Type : int
    {
        MDT_Effective_DPI = 0,
        MDT_Angular_DPI = 1,
        MDT_Raw_DPI = 2,
        MDT_Default = MDT_Effective_DPI
    }

    [DllImport("Shcore.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int GetDpiForMonitor(IntPtr hmonitor, Monitor_DPI_Type dpiType, out uint dpiX, out uint dpiY);

    private void AppTitleBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if customization is supported.
        // The method returns true on Windows 10 since Windows App SDK 1.2, and on all versions of
        // Windows App SDK on Windows 11.
        if (AppWindowTitleBar.IsCustomizationSupported() is true)
        {
            SetDragRegionForCustomTitleBar(_appWindow);
        }
    }

    private void AppTitleBar_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if customization is supported.
        // The method returns true on Windows 10 since Windows App SDK 1.2, and on all versions of
        // Windows App SDK on Windows 11.
        if (AppWindowTitleBar.IsCustomizationSupported() is true
            && _appWindow.TitleBar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar is true)
        {
            // Update drag region if the size of the title bar changes.
            SetDragRegionForCustomTitleBar(_appWindow);
        }
    }

    private AppWindow GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        WindowId wndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
        return AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(wndId);
    }

    private double GetScaleAdjustment()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        WindowId wndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
        DisplayArea displayArea = DisplayArea.GetFromWindowId(wndId, DisplayAreaFallback.Primary);
        IntPtr hMonitor = Win32Interop.GetMonitorFromDisplayId(displayArea.DisplayId);

        // Get DPI.
        int result = GetDpiForMonitor(hMonitor, Monitor_DPI_Type.MDT_Default, out uint dpiX, out uint _);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not get DPI for monitor.");
        }

        uint scaleFactorPercent = (uint)(((long)dpiX * 100 + (96 >> 1)) / 96);
        return scaleFactorPercent / 100.0;
    }

    private void SetDragRegionForCustomTitleBar(AppWindow appWindow)
    {
        // Check to see if customization is supported.
        // The method returns true on Windows 10 since Windows App SDK 1.2, and on all versions of
        // Windows App SDK on Windows 11.
        if (AppWindowTitleBar.IsCustomizationSupported() is true
            && appWindow.TitleBar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar is true)
        {
            double scaleAdjustment = GetScaleAdjustment();

            RightPaddingColumn.Width = new GridLength(appWindow.TitleBar.RightInset / scaleAdjustment);
            LeftPaddingColumn.Width = new GridLength(appWindow.TitleBar.LeftInset / scaleAdjustment);

            List<Windows.Graphics.RectInt32> dragRectsList = new();

            Windows.Graphics.RectInt32 dragRectL;
            dragRectL.X = (int)((LeftPaddingColumn.ActualWidth) * scaleAdjustment);
            dragRectL.Y = 0;
            dragRectL.Height = (int)(AppTitleBar.ActualHeight * scaleAdjustment);
            dragRectL.Width = (int)((IconColumn.ActualWidth
                                    + TitleColumn.ActualWidth
                                    + LeftDragColumn.ActualWidth) * scaleAdjustment);
            dragRectsList.Add(dragRectL);

            Windows.Graphics.RectInt32 dragRectR;
            dragRectR.X = (int)((LeftPaddingColumn.ActualWidth
                                + IconColumn.ActualWidth
                                + TitleTextBlock.ActualWidth
                                + LeftDragColumn.ActualWidth
                                + PersonButtonColumn.ActualWidth) * scaleAdjustment);
            dragRectR.Y = 0;
            dragRectR.Height = (int)(AppTitleBar.ActualHeight * scaleAdjustment);
            dragRectR.Width = (int)(RightDragColumn.ActualWidth * scaleAdjustment);
            dragRectsList.Add(dragRectR);

            Windows.Graphics.RectInt32[] dragRects = dragRectsList.ToArray();

            appWindow.TitleBar.SetDragRectangles(dragRects);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I went back and reviewed everything that I had done to get this working. The problem I had originated when I used the Windows `ExtendsContentIntoTitleBase` instead of the `AppWindow.TitleBar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar` call. I must have picked it up from examples like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3#examples).

Answer (score 0):

do you want a simple way? install WinUICommunity and use TitleBar Control

https://github.com/WinUICommunity/WinUICommunity